# Adding Group of Controls on Pressing Enter Key

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

Being new to WPF/MVVM, i would like to know the following,

I have made a Grid Row with a Combo Box & a TextBox. Now if i press enter from Textbox than a new similar row must be generated in next line.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: You should really, *really* look into using the MVVM pattern with WPF, because if you are using it the WinForms way, you are losing a lot of what makes WPF so great.

Comment: Second @nvoigt - use MVVM. With MVVM the auto display of calculated totals is trivial.

Comment: Really, .... look into MVVM. I did not see this kind of horror since I left Winforms.

Comment: @nvoigt Tell me how i can generate the Rows in Grid dynamically using MVVM, because i am still not able to Figure it using DataTemplate

Comment: I would not use a grid, but rather another container control like `ListView`. You then bind the `ItemSource` to your ViewModel `IEnumerable` (preferably `ObserableCollection`).